# case class explicit parameters that are implicit inside

Tags: scala, implicit

Is there a way to avoid code such as this?

```
case class Foo(bar: Int, baz: String, ec: ExecutionContext) {
  implicit val implicitEc = ec  

  .... 
}
```

Adding implicit in the front of the parameter list has a different effect than desired. I wish the executionContext to be an explicit parameter to the constuctor, but be treated as an implicit variable inside the class body.

Comment: Does't a case class Foo(bar: Int, baz: String, implicit ec: ExecutionContext) works ?

Comment: According to Alexey Romanov it does, however I need it the first (and only) parameter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
case class Foo(bar: Int, baz: String, implicit val ec: ExecutionContext)
```

works. Note that it can't be applied to the first parameter. In that case I would use your original code (except using `implicit private def` instead of `implicit val`, so you don't create an extra field and don't pollute the API). If you have multiple classes like that, this solution should work (adjust names to taste):

```
abstract class MakeTheParameterImplicit[A](implicit protected val dontOverrideInChildren: A)

case class Foo(ec: ExecutionContext) extends MakeTheParameterImplicit[ExecutionContext]()(ec)
```

Comment: What if it is the only parameter?

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit unfortunate that one has to succumb to such tricks. Scala is really good at removing boilerplate and redundancy, but alas it is not perfect.